# Accessing returned struct variables

Tags: c

So I have the function top() to return the top of the a stack (implemented as a linked list). It returns a Node struct. I am getting errors when I try to access the variables of the returned struct.

```
typedef struct nodeStrcut{
    int x,y;
    struct nodeStrcut* next;
}Node;

Node top(Node** head){
    return **head; 
}

void push(Node** head, int x, int y){
    //create a new node to contain the value 
    Node* newPtr = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newPtr->x = x;
    newPtr->y = y; 
    newPtr->next = *head;
    *head = newPtr; 
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    Node* stack;
    stack = NULL;
    push(&stack, 3, 3);
    push(&stack, 2, 3);
    push(&stack, 3, 5);
    printf("Node value: %d, %d\n", (pop(&stack)).x, (pop(&stack)).y); 
    return -1;
}
```

And then I get the following error:

```
project.c: In function ‘main’:
error: request for member ‘x’ in something not a structure or union
error: request for member ‘y’ in something not a structure or union
```

I know that I could use stack->x to get values but I need to have a function that returns value from the stop of the stack. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you return a pointer to a Node?

Comment: `(pop(&stack)).x`-> `(top(&stack)).x`?

Comment: You've not declared `pop()` in the code shown (you have defined and therefore declared `top()`).  You have indeterminate behaviour because you call `pop()` twice in the argument list to `printf()` and you can't tell which order the calls will be made in.  The `top()` function can be called twice safely; it'll return the same value each time until something else changes the stack.

Comment: Show the pop function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Node* newPtr = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714). The following is sufficient:

```
Node *newPtr = malloc (sizeof *newPtr);
```

The address for `head` isn't changing in `top`, so there is no need to pass the address of `head`, e.g.

```
Node top (Node *head){
    return *head;
}
```

You shouldn't return a *negative* value from `main()`. There are two defined returns:

```
EXIT_SUCCESS: 0
EXIT_FAILURE: 1
```

[**See What should main() return in C and C++?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Putting it altogether:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct nodeStrcut{
    int x,y;
    struct nodeStrcut* next;
} Node;

Node top (Node *head){
    return *head;
}

void push (Node **head, int x, int y) {

    Node *newPtr = malloc (sizeof *newPtr);
    newPtr->x = x;
    newPtr->y = y;
    newPtr->next = *head;
    *head = newPtr;
}

int main (void) {

    Node *stack = NULL;

    push (&stack, 3, 3);
    push (&stack, 2, 3);
    push (&stack, 3, 5);

    printf ("Node value: %d, %d\n", (top (stack)).x, (top (stack)).y);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/stacktop
Node value: 3, 5
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's just a typo (`pop` instead of `top`), such that you actually call a library function not returning your `Node` type. Write `printf("Node value: %d, %d\n", top(&stack).x, top(&stack).y);` and it should work as expected.

Comment: And you should be able to use `top(&stack).x` without the extra parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass in a pointer to a pointer in `top()`. It's sufficient to change the function definition from `Node top(Node** head)` to `Node top(Node* head)`.

Now you won't need to pass in the address of `stack` when calling the following (without spelling mistakes):

```
printf("Node value: %d, %d\n", (top(stack)).x, (top(stack)).y);
```